# Insert Row in the excel

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I'm populating the data from ms access to excel through VBA. My db contains a number of group detail i want to separate the group members during the population time the problem is that at the end of the each group i wants to insert 2 rows in the excel sheet I'm using the below mentioned code but I does not work is any possible?

```
Dim varConnection
Dim varSQL
Dim cal, cal1, x


   varConnection = "ODBC; DSN=MS Access Database;DBQ=table.accdb; Driver={Driver do Microsoft Access (*.accdb)}"


   varSQL = "SELECT leftman.Productname,leftman.Description,leftman.SULM,leftman.MTR,leftman.meter1 FROM leftman INNER JOIN Product ON leftman.gid = Product.Productname ORDER BY Product.ID, leftman.ID"
   With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=varConnection, Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("B4"))
           .CommandText = varSQL
           .Name = "Query-39008"
           .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

   End With
   x = Range("J5", Range("J5").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

    k1 = 5
    k2 = 6
    For i = 0 To x
    s = k1 + i
    s1 = k2 + i

   If Range("J" & s & "").Value = Range("J" & s1 & "").Value Then
   msgbox "same group"

   Else

   Range("J" & s & "").Select
   ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
   ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
   k1 = 5 + 2
   k2 = 6 + 2

   End If
   Next i
```

first i retrieve the data in groupwise from access
       X is my row count
       K1 is cell 1 and K2 is cell2 i am comparing the cell 1 with cell 2 through looping if the data is not
       match then it is consider an another group so after that cell i wants to insert the 2 rows

Answer (score 1):

You can work back ways:

```
x = Range("J5", Range("J5").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

For i = x To 5 Step -1
    s = i
    s1 = i - 1

    If Range("a" & s & "").Value = Range("a" & s1 & "").Value Then
        MsgBox "same group"

    Else

        Range("a" & s & "").Select
        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert
        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert

    End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the 'Select' function can be unreliable. You can avoid it by using the following:

```
.Rows(s).Insert Shift:=xlDown
```

assuming I am understanding correctly that 's' is the row number.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Range("a" & s & "").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
```